# How do you call those pages between click and going to another store?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hyperlink

I'm realy curious how you call those pages. It is a bit hard to explain but take a look at this example:

[Example website](http://www.beslist.nl/products/accessoires/accessoires_2596345_3538679/)

When you click on a product and leaving the website to another one you get some kind of between page with "Thank you for visiting our website! You will be forwarded to the webshop now!"

How do you call those pages and is there an easy way (WordPress Plugin) to get those pages when click on an outgoing link?

Any help and information is welcome because I cant find it (because I dont know how you call those pages;))

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: You mean this one? http://www.beslist.nl/load_product.html

Comment: Yes but you have different kinds... Take a look at this one when leaving the website : http://www.jouwaanbieding.nl/ 
But I mean that page... How do you call those and is it easy to integrate in website (I prefer a WordPress plugin or something)

Comment: I guess it's just a redirect. The `single.php` page is just a spinning icon and a bit of text, togheter with a redirect link. If you know WordPress, you could bulid something like the youself. But I don't know if there is a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

They are called `popups` in which you can set your desired static/dynamic content.

The plugin used in your example is `Jquery Lightbox(Fancybox)`.

[See the example](http://fancybox.net/)

Comment: The first link I posted it not a popup. It is a page between the click and other website. And if it is a Popup how did they manage to create to be between two pages?